# Are space-leaks in GHC Haskell always fixable?

Tags: haskell, ghc

As I learn about Haskell, I'm getting impression that [surprising space leaks](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2607) ([also here](https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-01-10-nested-loop-space-leak)) are one of the most important barriers to adoption.

It's not clear to me whether any program can always be rewritten so that it does not suffer from space leaks all else being equal.

Comment: What do you mean by “any program”? _Any piece of Haskell code that works_, or rather _any algorithm that can be implemented in other languages without memory leaks_?

Comment: It's an interesting question, if you can clarify it. One issue is I suspect that a "space leak" is in some sense by definition "fixable" (e.g. an algorithm that uses O(n) memory for which no better algorithm is known would never be termed a "space leak")

Comment: @leftaroundabout I meant to ask whether any piece of Haskell that works can be rewritten in Haskell so that it does not have space leaks.

Comment: @jberryman I like your definition. A counterexample would be a Haskell program that uses asymptotically more memory than equivalent imperative algorithm which cannot be rewritten to help GC reclaim unused memory. I wonder if there is a class of programs fixable by impure RTS specific hacks - it's certainly better to have this option than none.